# I am trying to use TinyMCE with dynamically generated textareas, but the IDs are always set by something else

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating, tinymce-5

I am using Underscore, React, and TinyMCE for one of my games.

Part of the game management has a editing screen with multiple TinyMCE textboxes, so I need that dynamically-generated id.

That's why in the template, I use textareas with dynamically generated IDs like this:

```
<textarea id="{{'game_' + g.id}}" class="gameDesc">
</textarea>
```

which should result in a textarea like this:

```
<textarea id="game_7" class="gameDesc"></textarea>
```

And then I use it to set the value of my selector in my TinyMCE component like this:

```
return (
    <Editor
        initialValue={gameDesc}
        init={{
            selector: 'textarea#game_' + gameId,
            height: 500,
            plugins: [
                'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor'
            ],
            toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | fontselect fontsizeselect formatselect |
        }}
        value={contentEditor}
        onEditorChange={handleEditorChange}
    />
)
```

But whenever I run it, I see that somehow the ID of my textarea is being changed like this:

```
<textarea id="tiny-react_75536734221618409165824" />
```

I have no idea where or how that's being set.

Just to make sure, I added a test line like this:

```
<div id="{{'game_' + g.id}}">TESTING</div>
```

And it does render correctly like this:

```
<div="game_7">TESTING</div>
```

So I'm not sure what's going on.

Has anyone ever run into an issue like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the TinyMCE React component there is a parameter that you can pass to the `<Editor>` tag to set the `id`:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/#id

> An id for the editor. Used for retrieving the editor instance using
> the tinymce.get('ID') method. Defaults to an automatically generated
> UUID.

Comment: Thank you. I am using the TinyMCE React component, and I render it like this: `this.renderComponent(tinyMCEeditor, { game: this.model.attributes }, '.gameArea');` So in the example they show, `id=uuid`, I can just do `id=gameId` ?  thanks again!

Comment: To answer your comment -- yes as that is happening in JavaScript just as your selector code dynamically creates the selector.

Comment: So I tried it, `return ( <Editor id='gameId' ` but it just generates a textarea like this, `<textarea id="gameId" `

Comment: I had to do it like this:  `id={gameId.toString()}`